# Error 13 Type mismatch and Error 9 Script out of range

Tags: excel

I created a similar macro to generate pivot table and chart, and it worked fine. Now I need to create a new one, so I applied the same code but revised it accordingly. But this time, VBA told me I have error 9'Script out of range, and sometimes error 13'Type Mismatch after I executed the code. I repeated running the code several time, but sometimes it gave error 13, sometimes it gave error 9. So I am confused. The code is the almost the same that worked for my previous work. I am wondering if somebody could point out the place where I get wrong. I appreciate it. Thank you!

```
Sub Diff_Milg()
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim ObjField As PivotField
Dim objPivot As PivotTable
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim lblRng As Range
Dim grRng As Range

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlDown).Row


Sheets("Sheet1").Select



Set SourceRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:D" & LastRow)

Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "Different Milg"

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add( _
SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
SourceData:=SourceRange).CreatePivotTable _
TableDestination:=Sheets("Different Milg").Range("A1"), _
TableName:="Different Mileage", _
DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion11    *Error Happens here

ActiveSheet.PivotTableWizard TableDestination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Different Mileage").PivotFields("ProductionYM")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Different Mileage").PivotFields("Milg")
.Orientation = xlColumnField
.Position = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Different Mileage").PivotFields("FailPartId")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Name = "CountofMilg"
 .Function = xlCount
.Position = 1
End With
Set objPivot = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Different Mileage")
'Set range of field label whose items are to be grouped:
Set lblRng = objPivot.PivotFields("Milg").LabelRange
lblRng.Group Start:=0, End:=36000, by:=5000
 'to ungroup:
 'lblRng.Ungroup

 'Set Range of dates to be grouped
 Set grRng = objPivot.PivotFields("ProductionYM").DataRange
```

Comment: Could you specify on what lines the errors occur?  Subscript out of range means you're referring to something by name that doesn't exist or is spelled incorrectly.  Maybe it has something to do with the pivot tables being collapsed and hiding the fields you're looking for?  But it's probably impossible to help without knowing where the error occurs

Comment: Hi thanks! I indicated the error right in the 'DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion11'